# CSS3 Transform/Transition blinks when page is loaded

Tags: html, css

I have 2 similar things here, but on first one inputs kinda 'blinks' when page is loaded, and on second is normal. So I can't find why I got 'blinks' on first one... Maybe you can't see it on codepen, but in normal browser you can see it... <-- You know what I mean, sorry about my poor English.

First pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGzEKN

```
    input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="text"]:hover,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:hover,
input[type="password"]:focus {
  background: rgba(60, 68, 76, 0.75);
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Second pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meKQbN this one is working fine.

```
    .login_field label,
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  background: #3b4148;
  outline: none;
  transition: all .6s ease;
  color: #FF79AB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know I had a similar problem when using bootstrap affix plugin. Thing about codepen is you don't write all the information in one place (like in a text editor starting with Doctype).

write your code on codepen in the html area with this html syntax

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The browser understands when it reads an html document with this format. Codepen you don't use that or need it, but it also have some setbacks so I hope this work. Go ahead and try. Cheers!